# How is data stored during C programming?

Tags: c, int, storage

an example;

```
main()
{
    int x=123;
}
```

so, `x` is an `int` type variable and 2 byte is allocated for `int` (*current assumption, this may differ machine wise.*)

Let's say, address `2000` and `2001` are allocated for `x`. So, how is data `123` stored using these addresses?
I am a beginner in C, so simple language would be helpful.

I am referring "Computing Fundamentals & C Programming" by E Balagurusamy [Mc Graw Hill Education].

Comment: No, `sizeof(int)` bytes will be allocated for `x` (or rather `sizeof x`). This may or may not be two bytes. In fact on most systems today it will be *four* bytes.

Comment: As for how the number will be stored, first of all learn about [the binary number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number), then learn about [*endianness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking how the number is spread across multiple bytes? Maybe you should read about ["endianness"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

Comment: The "how" of your question is unclear. Which part of storing a value are you interested in? The coding, as indicated by comment by Someprogrammerdude? The size? The physical aspect of how a computer can keep an information for short times? The logistics aspect of how the value gets from CPU to memory?

Comment: Note that `main()` as the definition of the main function has been invalid in standard C for the whole of the current millennium.  It was allowed in pre-standard C and in C90; it was disallowed in C99 onwards.  You should use `int main(void)` for preference, though `int main()` is OK — but the return type is mandatory.  If your text book talks about 2-byte `int` and doesn't use the modern style, then maybe you should get a better, more recent text book.  (Also, for the code shown, a good compiler will optimize `x` away because it is never used, so it won't be stored at all.)

Comment: You are probably following some book on C Programming. If it is so then what book is that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When I think about storage of variables in C, mostly I think about machine-independent boxes.  So given

```
int x = 123;
```

my first thought is just that it looks like this:

```
   +-----------+
x: |    123    |
   +-----------+
```

And since this is a local variable, I know that this little box is on the stack. (More on this below.)

Now, you asked about the individual bytes, and you imagined a two-byte `int` starting at address `2000`.  So here's how that would look, in more detail.  To emphasize the contents of the individual bytes, I'm going to switch to hexadecimal:

```
         +------+
x: 2000: | 0x7b |
         +------+
   2001: | 0x00 |
         +------+
```

You've probably figured this out, but that number `0x7b` is part of the hexadecimal representation of `123`.  The decimal number `123` has the hexadecimal representation `0x007b`.  This does assume a two-byte integer, although it's worth noting that these days, most machines you're likely to use will use four bytes.  I've also shown the situation for "little endian" storage, which is the convention that most machines use today.  The lower-numbered byte is the least-significant byte.

Since `123` is actually just a 7-bit number, it occupies only one of the two bytes, and the other one is zero.  To be really sure we understand how the two bytes are laid out, suppose we assign a new value to x:

```
x = 12345;
```

The hexadecimal representation of `12345` is `0x3039`, so the picture in memory changes to this:

```
         +------+
x: 2000: | 0x39 |
         +------+
   2001: | 0x30 |
         +------+
```

Finally, for comparison, suppose I said

```
long int y = 305419896;
```

And suppose this was on a machine with the opposite, big-endian byte order.  Suppose that `long int`s are four bytes, and suppose the compiler chose to put `y` at address 3000.  That random-looking number `305419896` has the hexadecimal representation `0x12345678`, so the situation in memory (again, assuming big-endian byte order) would look like this:

```
         +------+
y: 3000: | 0x12 |
         +------+
   3001: | 0x34 |
         +------+
   3002: | 0x56 |
         +------+
   3003: | 0x78 |
         +------+
```

With big-endian storage, the low-order address contains the most-significant byte, meaning that the number reads left-to-right (here top-to-bottom) in memory.  But as I said, most machines you're likely to use today are little-endian.

As I mentioned, since `x` in your example was a local variable, it will typically be stored on the function call stack.  (As a commenter has pointed out, there's no guarantee that C even has a stack, but most do, so let's go with that assumption.)  To see the difference between local and global variables, and also show how a couple of other datatypes are stored, let's look at a slightly bigger example, and let's expand our scope to imagine all of memory.  Suppose I write

```
int g = 456;
char s[] = "hello";

int main() {
    int x = 123;
    char s2[] = "world";
    char *p = s;
}
```

Typically, global variables are stored in the lower part of memory, while the stack is stored "at the top", and grows down.  So we can imagine our computer's memory looking like this.  As you'll see, I've reversed the convention I was using in the earlier picture.  In this picture, memory addresses run *up* the page.  (Also the memory addresses are in hexadecimal now, too, and I'm dropping the `0x` notation.  Also I'm going back to little-endian byte order, but retaining the notion of a 16-bit machine. Also I'm going to show the character values as themselves, not in hex.  Also I'm showing unknown bytes as `??`.)

```
          +------+
    ffec: |  ??  |
          +------+
    ffeb: |  00  |
          +------+
x:  ffea: |  7b  |
          +------+
    ffe9: |  00  |
          +------+
    ffe8: | 'd'  |
          +------+
    ffe7: | 'l'  |
          +------+
    ffe6: | 'r'  |
          +------+
    ffe5: | 'o'  |
          +------+
s2: ffe4: | 'w'  |
          +------+
    ffe3: |  02  |
          +------+
p:  ffe2: |  80  |
          +------+
    ffe1: |  ??  |
          +------+
             .
             .
             .
          +------+
    0282: |  ??  |
          +------+
    0281: |  00  |
          +------+
    0280: | 'o'  |
          +------+
    0283: | 'l'  |
          +------+
    0282: | 'l'  |
          +------+
    0281: | 'e'  |
          +------+
s:  0280: | 'h'  |
          +------+
    0283: |  01  |
          +------+
g:  0282: |  c8  |
          +------+
    0281: |  ??  |
          +------+
```

This is a huge simplification, of course, but it should give you the basic idea, and I still find it useful to think about it this way, despite all of the esoteric possible complications which the commenters are busy discussing.  The next step might be to show how `malloc`'ed memory looks, and how things look when we've got several function calls active on the stack, but this answer is getting too long, so we'll save that for another day.

Comment: Quote: "...I know that this little box is on the stack". That is not entirely correct. The concept of a stack is completely implementation dependent. The C standard does not specify the use of a stack. Further - even on stack based implementations, local variables may be kept in registers and never reach the stack.

Comment: @4386427 (Or should I say @ 42ee7b ? :-) ) I've mentioned the issue in an extended discussion.

Answer (score 6):

You should not care about how is the data stored, but you should think how your program behaves (so think more about [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science))).

<sup>Your code is wrong. You need at least to have `int main(void)`</sup>

Be aware of possible [optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) by the compiler, and of the ["as-if" rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule).

Your compiler could:

- forget the variable entirely. In your example, `x` has no observable effect and a compiler could remove `int x = 123;`
- store the variable only in some [processor register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register) (so the variable does not sit in memory and has no memory address)
- put the variable in some slot of the current stack frame of your [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) (or perhaps elsewhere in memory).
- etc... (including some mix of previous cases)

Of course, if you add some observable [side-effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) (perhaps a `printf("x=%d\n", x);` as a statement after your `int x = 123;`  definition of an [automatic variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable)), the compiler would handle that variable very differently.

The C standard (read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) specifies (in English) not only the syntax, but also the semantics of the C programming language, that is the observable behavior of programs. An important and tricky notion is that of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (UB; the toy program in your question don't have any UB, but you'll soon code buggy programs which have some UB, and you need to learn how to avoid UB). Be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) of UB.

Some side-effects are not relevant. For example, heating your processor.

Current implementations (compilers and systems) can help you in understanding the behavior of your program. I recommend compiling with all warnings and debug info (so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) and [using the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/).

Comment: +1, With all due respect, do we really feel necessary to mention Undefined Behavior here? I can understand your intention to point OP in right direction, but considering OP's level of understanding and experience in programming, I personally feel that OP may feel that this code exhibits Undefined behavior, which it may not.

Comment: Yes, because UB is probably the most tricky point of C, and it concerns even beginners. Coding `printf("%d %d", x++, x++)` is a mistake every beginner can do.

Comment: I agree, but I thought its directly not related to *this* code. Good answer nonetheless :-)